# find out postgresql query progress

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, progress

I have ran an `UPDATE` query in postgresql. After 5 days it has not finished yet. Is it possible to check percentage of completeness of my query which I have ran previously. I want to know if it takes only 5 days later to complete for example, or 955 days!

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328)

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do that.

If you understand the PostgreSQL source code and you know the execution plan of your query and you have installed the debugging symbols, you can attach a debugger to the backend process, examine the stack and determine where approximately in the query execution you are.